# How to find the expected Fisher information for a parameter of exponential distribution in an iid sample?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-family, fisher-information

I am unclear to on how to find the Fisher information of $\lambda$ in the iid sample $X_1,...,X_n$.

Attempt:

I know that the fisher information for $X$ (not in a sample) would be:

$I(\lambda) = - E \frac{d^2}{d \lambda^2} ln(f(x|\lambda)) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$

Where: $f_x(x|\lambda) = \lambda exp[-\lambda x]$

Comment: Are you by any chance being asked to find the *observed* Fisher information?

Comment: nope. The expected fisher information $\lambda$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you mean for $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, then

$$f_X(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x_j} = \lambda^n e^{- \lambda \sum_jx_j}$$

and

$$l_X(\lambda) = \log f_X(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \log(\lambda^n e^{- \lambda \sum_jx_j}) = nlog(\lambda) - \lambda (\sum_j x_j)$$

$$\frac{\mathcal{d}}{\mathcal{d\lambda}} l_X(\lambda) = \frac{n}{\lambda} - \sum_{i=1}^n  x_i$$

$$\frac{\mathcal{d}^2}{\mathcal{d}\lambda^2} l_X(\lambda) = \frac{-n}{\lambda^2}$$

$$- E \left[ \frac{\mathcal{d}^2}{\mathcal{d}\lambda^2} l_X(\lambda) \right] = \frac{n}{\lambda^2}$$

Generally if $x_i$ are i.i.d. you can take the $I(\theta)$ for a single observation $x_i$ and obtain the Fisher information for $X$ with $nI(\theta)$